# Two excel tables - remove from table A any records also on table B

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables with 3 columns each (name, phone number, email address).  The columns in each table hold the same kind of values.

One table contains all contacts, while the other contains contacts who have RSVP'd to an event.  How can I do a boolean-type operation between these two tables to net just the contacts who have *not* yet been contacted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does each of the fields contain 1 value per person (one person has only one email in the field 'email address')?

Comment: @Jerry, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do it this way

1. Copy table A and table B to a single worksheet
2. Combine all columns (per table) into a single one
3. Compare the new columns with `=ISERROR(MATCH(<CRITERIA>,<CHECKCOLUMN>,0))`

[image]

#### Used formulas in that example

D2: `=A2 & "-" & B2 & "-" & C2` → autofill down
E2: `=ISERROR(MATCH(D2,F:F,0))` → autofill down
F2: `=G2 & "-" & H2 & "-" & I2` → autofill down

Comment: Is there an easy way to then go through and delete from Table A any records marked "false"?

Comment: Of course: In my example I would apply an `auto filter` on columns A:E. Then filter in column E for `FALSE`. Now, only lines with FALSE  are displayed. Select all and delete them. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `VLOOKUP()` or a `MATCH()` function on the email since this is a unique field, but I would prefer using `MATCH()` here since you don't actually need the values in the second table.

Let's say that the second table is in `Sheet2` and first table (in `Sheet1`) has headers in cells A1 through C1 and the information starts in row 2. Put this formula in cell D2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Sheet1'!C2,'Sheet2'!C:C,0)), "Contact RSVP'd", "Not yet contacted")
```

You can change the results in the quotes as you wish.

If the two tables are in the same sheet, you can drop `'Sheet1'!` and `'Sheet2'!` altogether from the formula.